# Why does this code have a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault

I find that that while running this code it says:
`Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x7fff3010efcc)`

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int d[20],n,k,j,i,a[100000000],count=0;
//long long int i,a[100000000];
cin>>n>>k;
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    cin>>d[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    a[i]=i;
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        if(a[i]%d[j]==0)
        {
            a[i]=0;
        }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i]!=0)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
cout<<count;

}
```

Comment: There are multiple bugs in this. Each answer at the time of this writing highlights one bug.

Answer (score 1):

The stack has overflowed. There is no place for `int a[100000000]` as its size exceeds the default stack size (1MB on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

If we don't know the values of `n` and `k`, we can't respond appropriately to your question.

By example, if you give the value `21` to `k`, you write (`cin >> d[i]`) `d` in position `20`; this can cause the segmentation fault.

Suggestions:

1) run your program in a debugger

2) check the values for `n` and `k`

3) and use `std::vector` instead old C-style arrays and `at()` instead `operator[]` (by example: `cin >> d.at(i)`, `a.at(i) = i`, etc. instead `cin >> d[i]`, `a[i] = i`, etc.) because `at()` perform a bound checking.

Comment: The value of n can be anything between1 ≤n≤ 1000000000 and 1< k<20; also if you want to understand the program more here's the question

Comment: @Raikan10 - so you need another zero in `a` dimension (`100000000` instead of `1000000000`); and, as pointed by AVK (+1), `a` is to big for the stack; so I suggest the use of a `std::vector`, or a `std::deque` (heap instead of stack); and better: avoid the use of `a`: you don't need it